# IC quadruple 3 input positive and gate

Tags: integrated-circuit

Is there an IC that have 4 and gate with 3 input each?
I have searched that only NAND gate have that and I know that using inverter to the output to produce the output in the AND gate, but it cost more so is there an IC like that?

Comment: There's 4073 and 7411 but you need 2 of them and you will have 2 spare.

Comment: Are you able to consider a PLA? http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-0364-PLD-ATF16V8B-8BQ-8BQL-Datasheet.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to find an IC with four gates with three inputs each, as that would take 4*(3 inputs + 1 output) + power + gnd, or 18 pins which is not a standard logic package.

There are several logic ICs with **three** gates with **three** inputs each: 3 * (3 + 1) + 2 = 14 pins, which along with 16 pins is a standard package.

```
7410    triple 3-input NAND gate (available in HC and HCT versions)
7411    triple 3-input AND gate (available in HC and HCT versions)
4023    triple 3-input NAND gate
4073    triple 3-input AND gate
```

plus OR gates, NOR gates etc.

Comment: 2 fast for me. Yea I can't seem to find one that exists.

Comment: sorry for late reply, it seem it doesn't exist

Comment: I have already found an alternative solution, thanks for the time :D

Answer (score 0):

I only know of standard logic and gates packages with 3*3-input ands as the biggest standard package. I think you have to consider alternatives, like using more than one package.